# Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use

Tags: ubuntu, redis, nosql

When i try to run redis-server it will show this error:

```
# Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
16954:M 15 Sep 14:49:56.350 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
16954:M 15 Sep 14:49:56.350 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

I also tried to show which process use this port by using:

```
fuser -k -n tcp 6379
```

But this command doesn't return anything.

Comment: Same problem here, in my case I already run my redis server, so I can't run it twice. TO check if it already running go to redis folder in my case redis-6.2.5/src then run ./redis-cli

Answer (score 0):

Something's binding that port, try another approach to finding culprit: https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/